# php dynamic select option set to default value after you come back to page (reset select option after form submite)

Tags: php, html

```
<select id = "test" name = "test"> 
<option value = "">default option </option>

<?php
            

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

            $result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT id,name FROM center');
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
              $selected = (isset($_POST['list']) && $_POST['list'] ==  $row['id']) ? 'selected' : '';
              echo "<option value='$row[id]' $selected >$row[name]</option>";
            }
            ?>
</select>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['test']))
{

// unhide and display a bunch of stuff
}
```

Hi all, so my issue is that once the user submits the form. Leave the page and come back. The selected option in the while loop is still selected, however isset($_POST['test']) is no longer register so the code below no longer shows. So it just shows that one option, and the default option. (nothing to do or select cause isset(post) no longer set when they come to the page

The issue is that since the isset is no longer set the user can't do anything. even when page refresh. All they have is one select box option. But if the user select the same option before it would've generated the code in the if isset(post['test'])

I want it so that once the form has been submitted to reset the first select option to it's default option or show the second half when the user comes back to the page and the dynamic select option is still save

I apologize because my laptop is still broken and I can't copy and paste my code so I wrote some code and wrote a part of someone else code. I am trying to get my laptop fix as soon as possible but with the current situation I am having trouble getting it repair quickly

Comment: Use `session` to store previous submitted data, and if the user go back extract and set this data to vars.

Comment: can you provide psudo code or code? I'm still a bit confuse